# Nested Table help in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

I am stuck on this exercise with HTML nested tables, can someone offer some help?

I can't seem to get the blue header to span the 12 columns I've set.

I set the `colspan` on the two second row `<td>`s to `colspan="6"` so each will take up half the width, while the `colspan="12"` on the header I thought would fill the entirety of the width, but it's being limited to half the width, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is what it's supposed to look like:

[image: The layout]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>

        body {background-color:black;
        }

        table {
                width:580px;
                height:300px;
                border:2px auto;
                margin: 0px auto;
            }

        .grey {background-color:grey;}
        .blue {background-color:blue;}
        .red  {background-color:red; color:grey;}
        .cyan {background-color:cyan;color:grey;}
        .green {background-color:lime;color:grey;}


        #outer {color: white;
           text-align: center;

        }
        #greytext {
                    color:#333;
                    width:150px;
            }

        #nested {width:150px;
                 height:90px;
                 border:2px solid black;
                 }

        #nestedtext {color:#666;
                     width:60px;
                     font-size:21px;}      

           }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td ="colspan="12" rowspan="1" class="blue"><p id="outer">Outer Table</p></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td rowspan="6" colspan="6" class="grey">
            <p id="greytext">This is an example of nested tables.
            </td>

            <td rowspan="6" colspan="6" class="grey">
                <table id="nested">
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="4" colspan="1">
                            <p id="nestedtext">Pick a color</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr rowspan="1" colspan="2">
                          <td class="red"><p>Red</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr rowspan="1" colspan="2">
                        <td class="cyan"><p>Blue</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr rowspan="1" colspan="2">
                        <td class="green"><p>Green</p></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you tell me what actually you want brother. In simple language, like a table with this and this settled in this way. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I said in the post about spanning the blue top row to the 12 columns. Tyvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first cell you have a leading ="
Removing it fixes the problem

```css
 body {
   background-color: black;
 }
 table {
   width: 580px;
   height: 300px;
   border: 2px auto;
   margin: 0px auto;
 }
 .grey {
   background-color: grey;
 }
 .blue {
   background-color: blue;
 }
 .red {
   background-color: red;
   color: grey;
 }
 .cyan {
   background-color: cyan;
   color: grey;
 }
 .green {
   background-color: lime;
   color: grey;
 }
 #outer {
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
 }
 #greytext {
   color: #333;
   width: 150px;
 }
 #nested {
   width: 150px;
   height: 90px;
   border: 2px solid black;
 }
 #nestedtext {
   color: #666;
   width: 60px;
   font-size: 21px;
 }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="12" rowspan="1" class="blue">
      <p id="outer">Outer Table</p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="6" colspan="6" class="grey">
      <p id="greytext">This is an example of nested tables.
    </td>

    <td rowspan="6" colspan="6" class="grey">
      <table id="nested">
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="4" colspan="1">
            <p id="nestedtext">Pick a color</p>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr rowspan="1" colspan="2">
          <td class="red">
            <p>Red</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr rowspan="1" colspan="2">
          <td class="cyan">
            <p>Blue</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr rowspan="1" colspan="2">
          <td class="green">
            <p>Green</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Weeeee, ty Alfonso!

Silly little error, completely overlooked it when combing thru my code.

Comment: You have enough rep that you should recognize the fact that questions that are caused by minor typographical errors should be closed, not answered.

Comment: For me it's bad to say "it's a typo so I won't answer".Once it's clear the problem you can close the question, but first it's simpler to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple typo on the line: `<td ="colspan="12" rowspan="1" class="blue"><p id="outer">Outer Table</p></td>`

It should be: `<td colspan="12" rowspan="1" class="blue"><p id="outer">Outer Table</p></td>`

Works on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lajf9v0d/

Comment: Ty Frederik, haha.

Simple oversight.

Appreciate it!